# JSON not loading even onAfterRender

Tags: sapui5

I am currently tying to implement a JSON Model into a SAPUI5 App but in the Network Tab I can see the JSON File is still on (pending) even when onAfterRendering is reached which leads to my app failing to load the Model.

```
        "city": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "settings": {},
            "uri": "model/City.json",
            "preload": true
        }
```

Here is code from my manifest.json where the models are stated which is even set to  preload.
I am still really new to SAPUI5 so I thank you for your assistance upfront.

Comment: The json model loads Async unless you specify otherwise. You say the file is pending, So check if it loads after a while. If your bindings are correct, then the values should load once the model is available.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a typical structure for an SAPUI5 application where in this case I'm using a local Json File named `"products.json"`:

[image]

In your `manifest.json`, before creating an entry in the models property you must at least specify the uri of the local path to the Json file. You can create an entry in `"dataSources"` with an alias name like `"products"` and specifying the type:

```
"dataSources": {
   "products": {
      "uri": "model/products.json",
      "type": "JSON"
   }
}
```

You can now create an entry in `"models"`:

```
"models": {
   "productsModel": {
      "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
      "dataSource": "products"
   }
}
```

The name used for the entry name will be the name of the model. Leave it empty if you want to use it as the default component model.

For example: I'll be able to reach for my model by calling `this.getView().getModel("productsModel")`.

Now you just need to specify the type (in my case `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel`) and the `"dataSource"` alias.

Find a [good example here](http://Load%20local%20JSON%20model%20directly%20from%20the%20manifest.json).

[SAPUI5 Manifest Descriptor](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw751abap/7.51.0/de-DE/74/038a52dcd7404e82b38be6d5fb1458/frameset.htm)

Comment: I managed to load it by instantiating the model and then waiting with the calling of the model by using attachRequestCompleted.   I thank you for your help anyway.